# How can we change default label provider of eclipse ide's project explorer view to render file with customized label

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have a folder containing some xml files with some system generated names. I want to create a plugin which can replace the system generated name with the actual name of that file which is present in between name attribute of the xml file itself. I didnt find any way to modify the default label provider and I am newbie in eclipse plugin development.. Can any body tell me the appropriate way to achieve this task...

Comment: I don't think you can change the label provider for resources. You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer` and `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent` extension points to add non-resource based objects to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extend the Eclipse `org.eclipse.ui.decorators` extension point to provide a custom label.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.decorators"> 
    <decorator  
      id="YourDecorator"  
      label="Decorator Label"  
      state="false"  
      class="YourDecorator.class"  
      objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"  
      adaptable="true">  
    </decorator>  
</extension>
```

For more info, visit the following link: https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html